# SQL server connection using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I am trying to connect remote Microsoft SQL server using PDO.
Before installing required drivers (SQLSRV30) my phpinfo()'s configure command section shows-

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--without-dblib" "--without-pdo-dblib" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-
```

I have installed required drivers->php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll (I am using PHP 5.4 using APACHE server). I have also made required changes in php.ini file-

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

Despite this, when I tried making connection with MSSQL Server, error appears saying `undefined function mssql_connect()` and undefined function `sqlsrv_connect()`.

The php info page still says that-> "--without-pdo-mssql" in configure command section.

Kindly help where the problem is!

PS:1) When using ODBC odbc_connect() function works fine.
    2) I have refreshed Apache several times after editing.
    3) I have saved .ts files in the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\ext folder

Comment: Does the sqlsrv section appear in the output of phpinfo() after restarting the apache? If not check whether you've edited the correct php.ini (the path is also included in the output of phpinfo()) and check the php log file for startup errors.

Comment: @VolkerK  No, sqlsrv section does not appears in phpinfo(). I have checked the php.ini file mentioned in phpinfo(); It is the same file that I had edited. Also the error_log says no value for local and master value.

Comment: then set a value for error_log in the php.ini and try again. e.g. error_log=c:/temp/php_errors.log or some other valid file path. After restarting the apache check the contents of that file.

Comment: @VolkerK in addition to sqlsrv_pdo I had also saved php_pdo_mssql. could by any change they can conflict?

Comment: sqlsrv_pdo& php_pdo_mssql "could by any change they can conflict?" - no idea but I doubt it.

Comment: @VolkerK  the error_log file says-> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. What does this mean?

Comment: @VolkerK  I am using 64 bit processor

Comment: " I am using 64 bit processor " - interesting, do you also use the 64bit version of apache and php?

Comment: @VolkerK Yes it seems so, phpinfo() says- Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12

Comment: Then you'd need a 64bit build of the extension as well. No idea, were you'd get that from.

Comment: Then I should switch to apache 32 bit? I have searched the internet, I couldn't find 64 bit files of mssqlsrv. Anyways, thanks for help!

Comment: @VolkerK The problem is fixed. Big Thanks to you!. But in phpinfo() page still says that-> "--without-pdo-mssql" in configure command section. Is this thing static and not supposed to change when new drivers are added or I am missing something.

Comment: "--without-pdo-mssql" - yes, that was the optioned used with the configure command when php was compiled. It won't change (until you use another php5.dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php_sqlsrv_5x_ts.dlls provided by Microsoft are 32bit. They won't work for a 64bit build of php.
The source code is available at https://github.com/azure/msphpsql, so you might be able to compile a 64bit version yourself - if necessary.